# Using ag-grid with materializecss in angular 6

Tags: angular, materialize, angular6, ag-grid

I am using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) in angular 6. I want to use ag-grid but is not compatible with materializecss. [I added the sample image.](https://pasteboard.co/HAcEmhS.png)

How can I work compatibly with materializecss and ad-grid in angular 6?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the ag grid enterprise version?

Comment: Yes i have enterprise version

Comment: Because if you have it, you can ask a question directly to them. Find on the website: If you are an ag-Grid Enterprise Customer, please raise this in our Zendesk support system - contact info@ag-grid.com for access. This is our primary channel for Support.

Comment: If you want more help here can you provide a reproduction of your code on plunker or stackblitz. Because it seems that it's an issue with the html and css.Try to change the style of the element (like 100% width and 100% height)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I contacted them.